# install group_concat UDAF aggregate function in Vertica 7

Tags: vertica

I'd like to install the UDAF string functions that are pre-packaged in Vertica 7. Specifically would like to install group_concat.

Had previously installed this in Vertica 6 but things seem to have changed a bit.  E.g. there is no make file, but there is an install.sql/

Here's what I did:

```
$ vsql -U dbadmin -w secret
> \i /opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl/install.sql
```

This yields the following output:

```
------------------------------------
 Vertica Analytic Database v7.2.0-0
(1 row)

ALTER SESSION
vsql:/opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl/install.sql:5: ROLLBACK 4650:  Schema "TxtIndex" does not exist
vsql:/opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl/install.sql:6: NOTICE 4214:  Object "v_txtindex" already exists; nothing was done
CREATE SCHEMA
ALTER SESSION
CREATE LIBRARY
CREATE FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION
GRANT PRIVILEGE
```

It looks like it worked but installation failed:

```
dbadmin=> \i /opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl/isinstalled.sql 
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

The following query also fails

```
  SELECT id, group_concat(distinct organization) AS orgs FROM myschema.mytable GROUP BY id;
```

And specifically I get this error:

```
ERROR 3457:  Function group_concat(varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for group_concat(varchar)
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see group_concat() installation is commented in /opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl/install.sql (last two lines in this file).

group_concat() sources might be available in the HAVEN Marketplace.